# How to convert a map of two interfaces to a map of two structs

Tags: go

If we have an interface `A` and a struct `a` implementing it, and there's an object `aobj` which is of the type interface `A`, we can do the conversion with `aobj.(*a)`.

However, if I have 2 interfaces, say `A` and `B`, and two corresponding struct, `a` and `b`. And I also have a map between `A` and `B`, i.e. `map[A]B`. Is there any similar conversion from a `map[A]B` to a `map[a]b`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to range over the source map and type assert both key and value:

```
func assertMap(m map[A]B) map[a]b {
    out := make(map[a]b, len(m))
    for k, v := range m {
        out[k.(a)] = v.(b)
    }
    return out
}
```